# How to dynamically add and manipulate multiple, unique pictureboxes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

I'm a high-school student making a basic game for an assessment.
The game makes baseballs fly across the screen at the player, who bats them away.

All baseballs are contained in pictureboxes, and I need to be able to make an infinite number of them which can be individually referenced and moved, all during runtime.

I'm currently adding and storing pictureboxes in dictionaries.  However, whenever I create a new picturebox and add it to the form, it overrides any previously created pictureboxes on the form.

I need to find code that allows previously created pictureboxes to remain on the form while creating new ones.

For context, I have added the logic flow of my program below.

## Current Program Logic

Sub that randomly determines whether the ball will spawn on the left, right, north or south sides of the screen.

Sub that based on the above result, sets up a new "baseball" picturebox by altering a blank variable.

Sub that adds this as the Value to a dictionary, with the Key a variable called ballNameNumber.
At the same time, a random number is set as the Value for a dictionary called ballVelocity, with Key ballNameNumber.  This is multiplied by a variable called level, which increases as the game time increases.

So at this point, a ball has been created, with identical key names in 3 dictionaries that each store its picturebox values and speed.

Sub that randomly chooses 1 of 4 spawn locations, records the direction of the ball to a dictionary called ballDirection based on this value, then creates the ball at this location.

All these subs occur in this order per tick of a timer called tmrGameTime (interval 500), on a form called frmGame (size 700,700)

```
  'Dictionaries used to log and describe the movement of the balls onscreen.
Dim spawnedBalls As Dictionary(Of Integer, PictureBox) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, PictureBox)
Dim ballVelocity As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
Dim ballDirection As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

'Variables used in the composition of dictionaries.
Dim ballNameNumber As Integer = 1
Dim numberOfBalls As Integer = 0
Dim level As Integer = 1
Dim ball As New Picturebox

'Turns on the game timer
Private Sub frmGame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tmrGameTime.Enabled = True
    tmrGameTime.Start()
End Sub

'Sets values to the ball variable (must be done within a sub otherwise an error is dispayed)
Public Sub ballSetUpLeft(ByRef ballTemplate)
    ballTemplate.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ballTemplate.Width = 34
    ballTemplate.Height = 29
    ballTemplate.Top = 325
    ballTemplate.Left = 55
    ballTemplate.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
End Sub

Public Sub ballSetUpRight(ByRef ballTemplate)
    ballTemplate.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ballTemplate.Width = 34
    ballTemplate.Height = 29
    ballTemplate.Top = 325
    ballTemplate.Left = 593
    ballTemplate.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
End Sub

Public Sub ballSetUpTop(ByRef ballTemplate)
    ballTemplate.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ballTemplate.Width = 34
    ballTemplate.Height = 29
    ballTemplate.Top = 59
    ballTemplate.Left = 333
    ballTemplate.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
End Sub

Public Sub ballSetUpBottom(ByRef ballTemplate)
    ballTemplate.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ballTemplate.Width = 34
    ballTemplate.Height = 29
    ballTemplate.Top = 574
    ballTemplate.Left = 333
    ballTemplate.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
End Sub


'Generates a random speed for a spawned ball based on the level value.
Public Function generateBallSpeed(ByVal level) As Integer

    Randomize()
    Dim ans As Integer = (((Rnd() * 10) * level) + 1)
    Return ans

End Function


'Logs the ball data into dictionaries
Public Sub createBall(ByRef spawnedBalls, ByRef ballVelocity, ByRef ballNameNumber, ByRef numberOfBalls, ByRef ballTemplate)

    'Adds a new ball with name and ballTemplate values to the dictionary.
    spawnedBalls.Add(ballNameNumber, ballTemplate)

    Dim v As Integer = generateBallSpeed(level)
    'Using the matching name, adds a velocity value to the ball
    ballVelocity.Add(ballNameNumber, v)

End Sub


'Spawns ball at a specific location on the form.
Public Sub spawnBallAtPitcher()

    Randomize()
    Dim pitcher As Integer = Int((4 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
    Select Case pitcher
        Case 1
            Call ballSetUpLeft(ballTemplate)
            Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, ballTemplate)
            ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Left")
            ballNameNumber += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

        Case 2
            Call ballSetUpRight(ballTemplate)
            Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, ballTemplate)
            ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Right")
            ballNameNumber += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

        Case 3
            Call ballSetUpTop(ballTemplate)
            Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, ballTemplate)
            ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Top")
            ballNameNumber += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

        Case 4
            Call ballSetUpBottom(ballTemplate)
            Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, ballTemplate)
            ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Down")
            ballNameNumber += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

    End Select
End Sub

'Repeatedly spawns balls
Private Sub tmrGameTime_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrGameTime.Tick
    Call spawnBallAtPitcher()
End Sub
```

End Class

I expect that the pictureboxes will appear in random order on my form, until four a visible at different points (as any further pictureboxes will be created on top of the previous).  However, on picturebox is created and then jumps between spawn locations.  No error messages are received.

Comment: Instead of writing it twice, write it once as Dim spawnedBalls As New Dictionary(Of Integer, PictureBox)

Comment: Your `ballSetUpLeft` etc. need to be  `Function(...) As PictureBox`, returning a **new** PictureBox object each time the method is called. Remove all those `ByRef` things from everywhere.

Comment: I suggest you to use Random class to generate random numbers. Using Rnd and Randomize is not comfortable to use in LinqPad (need to add/import a certain Reference). Also this math `(4 - 1 + 1)`, why not just use `4`?

Comment: Instead of using 3 dictionaries to hold information of balls, velocities and directions, you can use a class to wrap all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're using only 1 reference of ball in your code. So each time you want to create another ball, you use replace the previous ball with your new ball. Change your code in the 4 procedures into functions then return the new ball.

```
'Sets values to the ball variable (must be done within a sub otherwise an error is dispayed)
Public Function ballSetUpLeft() As PictureBox
    Dim newBall As New PictureBox
    newBall.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    newBall.Width = 34
    newBall.Height = 29
    newBall.Top = 325
    newBall.Left = 55
    newBall.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
    Return newBall
End Function

Public Function ballSetUpRight() As PictureBox
    Dim newBall As New PictureBox
    newBall.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    newBall.Width = 34
    newBall.Height = 29
    newBall.Top = 325
    newBall.Left = 593
    newBall.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
    Return newBall
End Function

Public Function ballSetUpTop() As PictureBox
    Dim newBall As New PictureBox
    newBall.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    newBall.Width = 34
    newBall.Height = 29
    newBall.Top = 59
    newBall.Left = 333
    newBall.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
    Return newBall
End Function

Public Function ballSetUpBottom() As PictureBox
    Dim newBall As New PictureBox
    newBall.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    newBall.Width = 34
    newBall.Height = 29
    newBall.Top = 574
    newBall.Left = 333
    newBall.Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
    Return newBall
End Function
```

Then change how you call the functions (used to be procedures) like this:

```
Select Case pitcher
    Case 1
        Dim newBall = ballSetUpLeft()
        Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, newBall)
        ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Left")
        ballNameNumber += 1
        Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

    Case 2
        Dim newBall = ballSetUpRight()
        Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, newBall)
        ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Right")
        ballNameNumber += 1
        Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

    Case 3
        Dim newBall = ballSetUpTop()
        Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, newBall)
        ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Top")
        ballNameNumber += 1
        Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

    Case 4
        Dim newBall = ballSetUpBottom()
        Call createBall(spawnedBalls, ballVelocity, ballNameNumber, numberOfBalls, newBall)
        ballDirection.Add(ballNameNumber, "Down")
        ballNameNumber += 1
        Me.Controls.Add(spawnedBalls.Item(ballNameNumber - 1))

End Select
```

Now your balls won't be replaced each time you want to create another ball. I leave the task to animate the balls and removing the balls when the pitcher hit the balls.

I tried to reduce redundancy in your code. The 3 dictionaries are replaced by a single dictionary which hold the ball information (id, direction, velocity and the picture). Use enumeration instead of hard-coded numbers for direction. Use Random class instead of Randomize() and Rnd() functions.

```
Public Class frmGame
    'Dictionaries used to log and describe the movement of the balls onscreen.
    Private balls = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Ball)

    'Variables used in the composition of dictionaries.
    Private random As New Random
    Private lastBallID As Integer
    Private Const level As Integer = 1

    Private Sub frmGame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Turns on the game timer
        tmrGameTime.Enabled = True
        tmrGameTime.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrGameTime_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrGameTime.Tick
        'Repeatedly spawns balls
        spawnBallAtPitcher()
    End Sub

    'Spawns ball at a specific location on the form.
    Private Sub spawnBallAtPitcher()

        lastBallID += 1
        Dim pitcher As Direction = random.Next(4) + 1
        Dim newBall = createBall(lastBallID, pitcher, random)
        Controls.Add(newBall.Picture)

        'Logs the ball data into dictionaries
        balls.Add(lastBallID, newBall)

    End Sub

    'Create new ball, set its ID, direction, velocity and picture
    Private Function createBall(ballID As Integer, direction As Direction, rnd As Random) As Ball

        Return New Ball With {
            .BallID = ballID,
            .Direction = direction,
            .Velocity = generateBallSpeed(level, rnd),
            .Picture = generateBallPicture(direction)
        }

    End Function

    'Generates a random speed for a spawned ball based on the level value.
    Private Function generateBallSpeed(ByVal level As Integer, ByVal rnd As Random) As Integer

        Return (rnd.Next(10) + 1) * level

    End Function

    'Generates a new picture of ball
    Private Function generateBallPicture(direction As Direction) As PictureBox

        Dim location = generatePictureLocation(direction)

        Return New PictureBox With {
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            .Width = 34,
            .Height = 29,
            .Top = location.Y,
            .Left = location.X,
            .Image = My.Resources.Baseball_Sprite
        }

    End Function

    'Generates a location for new picture of ball
    Private Function generatePictureLocation(direction As Direction) As Point

        Select Case direction
            Case Direction.Left
                Return New Point(55, 325)
            Case Direction.Right
                Return New Point(593, 325)
            Case Direction.Top
                Return New Point(333, 59)
            Case Direction.Bottom
                Return New Point(333, 574)
        End Select

    End Function

End Class

Public Enum Direction
    Left = 1
    Right
    Top
    Bottom
End Enum

Public Class Ball

    Public Property BallID As Integer
    Public Property Velocity As Integer
    Public Property Direction As Integer
    Public Property Picture As PictureBox

End Class
```